# SentiStrength: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I tried to use SentiStrength with Python to classify text sentiment.

```
import sentistrength
from sentistrength import PySentiStr

senti = PySentiStr()
senti.setSentiStrengthPath('C:/Users/xx/SentiStrengthCom.jar')
senti.setSentiStrengthLanguageFolderPath ('C:/Users/xx/SentStrength_Data_Sept2011/')

str_arr = ['What a lovely day', 'What a bad day']
result = senti.getSentiment(str_arr, score='scale')
```

However, when I try to execute the last line, I get the error **[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**. However, the file is found by the system, as there is no error message when trying the code below.

```
SentiStrengthLocation = "C:/Users/xx/SentiStrengthCom.jar"
SentiStrengthLanguageFolder = "C:/Users/xx/SentStrength_Data_Sept2011/"

if not os.path.isfile(SentiStrengthLocation):
    print("SentiStrength not found at: ", SentiStrengthLocation)
if not os.path.isdir(SentiStrengthLanguageFolder):
    print("SentiStrength data folder not found at: ", SentiStrengthLanguageFolder)
```

I am really looking forward to your help! Thank you a lot!

Also, do you have any recommendations about how to perform a good sentiment analysis on Python?

**Edit**: I tried it on colab and there it works, is it possible that there are any admin rights that make it impossible to get the file?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [comment of an issue on github](https://github.com/zhunhung/Python-SentiStrength/issues/1#issuecomment-493772995), is it possible, that you don't have java installed? The package might be throwing the error because of that.

Comment: I've installed it but it still does not work...